# Referencing local variable without `this` in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to refer to the variable in the function component,
I think normally I use `this` to refer to the local variable.

However, in the function component, I can't use `this`.

Maybe, I am still confused by the function component though...

```
export default function TrackPage(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
       var playlist = 1;
    }
    function handleToolBarClick(){
        this.playlist // this is empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to store values either in state with `useState` (if changing it should cause a re-render), or in a ref with `useRef` (if you want to change the value without triggering a re-render).

Comment: Make a class component if you want `this`, Function components are stateless, or use hooks as Jayce mentions above, which essentially enable state to persist across render and be accessed via `useState`, etc.

Comment: Your useEffect function is incorrect. The usage need to be corrected.
Can you please correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript scope is strictly function based. Once a variable is not in your scope it is impossible for you to access it. Therefore you need to make the variable part of your scope:

```
export default function TrackPage(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    var playlist; // Make this variable available to both 
                  // useEffect and handleToolBarClick

    useEffect(() => {
       playlist = 1;
    },[]);

    function handleToolBarClick(){
        playlist // this works
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. component function can declare the variable here.